# How can I get characters until a specific character is reached?

Tags: c#

I want to get only data until the `"<img"` tag.

my codes are below: How can i complete it?

```
string body = row[2].ToString();
int num;
num = body.IndexOf("<img");
```

Comment: Is that a correct edit? that changes the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// first find the index of your starting point
int start = body.IndexOf("<img");
// then find the index of your ending point
int end = body.IndexOf("\"", start);
// then retrieve that portion of the string
string goods = body.Substring(start, end - start);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 string body = body.Substring(0, body.IndexOf("<img"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string interesting = body.Substring(0, num);
```